# Add 1 to a input value on click to checkbox in a php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I want add +1 to an input value when a checkbox is checked. I have try this code but inside the a loop don't works. I need this work inside a php loop, so, need to work only on the connected input.

this is my code

```
<div class="mix ">

        <div class="img-card">
          <img src="<?= $product->image_card ?>">
        </div>
        <p><?= $product->sub_title; ?></p>
        <div class="azione">
          <p>
            Check
            <input type="checkbox" name="PRD-<?= $product->sub_title ?>" id="<?= $product->sub_title ?>" value="SI" />
          </p>
            <div class="quantity-form">
              <span class="input-holder-form"><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span>
                  <input class="contatore" type="number" min="0" name="QNT-<?= $product->sub_title ?>" value="0">
              <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and give me this html:

```
<div class="mix">

        <div class="img-card">
          <img src="...">
        </div>
        <p>P Name</p>
        <div class="azione">
          <p>
            Check
            <input type="checkbox" name="PRD-name" id="P-ID" value="SI">
          </p>
            <div class="quantity-form">
              <span class="input-holder-form"><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span>
                  <input class="contatore" type="number" min="0" name="QNT-NIA - front desk" value="0">
              <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span>
          <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And this is my jQuery

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('.mix').addClass("checked");
        var $input = $('.mix.checked .contatore');
        var num = parseInt($input.val());
        var newNum = num + 1;
        $input.val(newNum);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.mix').removeClass("checked");
        var $input = $('.mix .contatore');
        var num = parseInt($input.val());
        var newNum = num * 0;
        $input.val(newNum);
    }
});
```

When I click on the checkbox add 1 to the input number, when I click off the checkbox go to zero.

But how to make it work only on the box connected and not on all?

Probably don't have to work with the `class checked`, but I have already try to use `closest`, `find`, `children` or `parent`.

Comment: Your `else` condition logic is a little odd. It will only ever result in a value of `0`...

Comment: When you do `x * 0` it will always `= 0`. Therefore, when you uncheck checkbox, it goes to zero.

Comment: You just need to add id or specific class on each checkbox and in the input field. that's more easier than using the `$('input:checkbox')`

Comment: Yes I know guys, I need the value go to 0. My problem is that this happens need do only in the connected box. The loop make a many box  and all go to 0. And also all the box have the class checked add 1. How make this works uniquely with the box connected to the checkbox?

Comment: thank @Dee I have a specific ID, I can use this?

Comment: in the else scenario i think they are just confused. why dont you just put zero as like this `$input.val(0);`
in the check and uncheck of checkbox try to play with some html attrib. for each box and input field add id or class with incrementing value

Comment: ill add my solution @MarcoRomano

Comment: @MarcoRomano can you edit the question with the whole code so i can show you how. thanks

Comment: yes @Dee I will add the html instead of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple sets of repeating elements, positional selectors work.

Your problem in your code is this line specifically:

```
var $input = $('.mix.checked .contatore');
```

That line ignores position and should only look at the `closest` element with that class, just as you have with the line above that one.

In addition you re-declare the same variables in side your function. No need to do that. I cleaned the code up a little and fixed the positional selector.

You also had a missing closing `</span>` in your example code and you didn't post more than 1 set so I had to make up my own repeating sets, hopefully matching yours as close as possible.

The code below treats each set separately only adding +1 to the input matching the checkbox in the same set instead of adding +1 to all inputs.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  var $closestParent = $(this).closest('.mix'),
    $input = $closestParent.find('.contatore'),
    num = parseInt($input.val()),
    newNum

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $closestParent.addClass("checked");
    newNum = num + 1;
  } else {
    $closestParent.removeClass("checked");
    newNum = num * 0;
  }
  
  $input.val(newNum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mix ">

  <div class="img-card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/15x15">
  </div>
  <p>
    Some Product Title
  </p>
  <div class="azione">
    <p>
      Check
      <input type="checkbox" name="someProduct1" id="someId1" value="SI" />
    </p>
    <div class="quantity-form">
      <span class="input-holder-form"><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span>
      <input class="contatore" type="number" min="0" name="someName1" value="0">
      <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix ">

  <div class="img-card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/15x15">
  </div>
  <p>
    Some Product Title
  </p>
  <div class="azione">
    <p>
      Check
      <input type="checkbox" name="someProduct1" id="someId1" value="SI" />
    </p>
    <div class="quantity-form">
      <span class="input-holder-form"><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span>
      <input class="contatore" type="number" min="0" name="someName1" value="0">
      <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is so nice! I understood what was the problem but I would never have arrived alone. Thank you I will study your solution for improve my knowledge! thanks again. ( About the html, here missing a jquery script where I add the </span> it's the part for let the + - works. )

Answer (score 1):

here is what im saying in the comment above. using the id and the attribute data-id to trigger and select the right fields. using incrementing ids and put it as data-id so you still have the counter you use in the loop.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  var idVal = $(this).data('id');
  var inputVal = parseInt($('#input_'+idVal).val());
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    inputVal+=1;
    $('#input_'+idVal).val(inputVal);
  } else {

    $('#input_'+idVal).val(0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mix ">

  <div class="img-card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/15x15">
  </div>
  <p>
    Some Product Title
  </p>
  <div class="azione">
    <p>
      Check
      <input type="checkbox" name="someProduct1" id="someId1" value="SI" data-id="1"/>
    </p>
    <div class="quantity-form">
      <span class="input-holder-form"><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span>
      <input class="contatore" id="input_1" type="number" min="0" name="someName1" value="0">
      <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix ">

  <div class="img-card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/15x15">
  </div>
  <p>
    Some Product Title
  </p>
  <div class="azione">
    <p>
      Check
      <input type="checkbox" name="someProduct2" id="someId2" data-id="2" value="SI" />
    </p>
    <div class="quantity-form">
      <span class="input-holder-form"><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span>
      <input class="contatore" id="input_2" type="number" min="0" name="someName2" value="0">
      <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mix ">

  <div class="img-card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/15x15">
  </div>
  <p>
    Some Product Title
  </p>
  <div class="azione">
    <p>
      Check
      <input type="checkbox" name="someProduct3" id="someId3" data-id="3" value="SI" />
    </p>
    <div class="quantity-form">
      <span class="input-holder-form"><span class="tiny-button-form plus">+</span>
      <input class="contatore" id="input_3" type="number" min="0" name="someName3" value="0">
      <span class="tiny-button-form minus"><strong>–</strong></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reapply, I link your solution. But honestly prefer the other one because I don't know how to add in the php loop add the data-id progressive. But thank you.

Comment: welcome. sample for clearer `data-id="<?php echo $ctr; ?>" id="someId<?php echo $ctr; ?>"`